# Read one item of array onclick javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, event-handling

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="quotes">
        <p id="par"></p>
    </div>

    <button class="btn" onClick="randomQuote()">button</button>
</div>

function randomQuote () {
    var array = [1,20,50,100];
}

document.getElementById("btn").onclick = randomQuote;
document.getElementById("par").innerHTML = array[0];//then on another btn click array[1]...
for(var i=0; i<array.length;i++){
    quote[i];
}
```

On "btn" click number 1 from array is shown in "par" paragraph
on another btn click number 2 shows up and 1 dissapear, and so on...

Comment: is your randomQuotes function copied completely?

Comment: Please elaborate more you question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use counter `cpt` as index to loop through the array and show the values :

```js
var array = [1,20,50,100];
var cpt = 0;

//Init the 'par' div before click
document.querySelector("#par").innerHTML = array[cpt];

function randomQuote () 
{
  if(cpt<array.length-1)
    cpt++;
  else
    cpt=0;

  document.querySelector("#par").innerHTML = array[cpt];
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="quotes">
    <p id="par"></p>
  </div>

  <button class="btn" onClick="randomQuote()">button</button>
</div>
```

Minified version could be :

```
function randomQuote () 
{
    document.querySelector("#par").innerHTML = array[cpt<array.length-1?++cpt:cpt=0];
}
```

**Snippet using Random color as you comment say :**

```js
var array = ["Quotes 1","Quotes 2","Quotes 3","Quotes 4"];
var cpt = 0;

//Init the 'par' div before click
document.querySelector("#par").innerHTML = array[cpt];
//Init Random Color before click
getRandomColor();

function randomQuote() 
{
  if(cpt<array.length-1)
    cpt++;
  else
    cpt=0;

  document.querySelector("#par").innerHTML = array[cpt];
}

function getRandomColor() 
{
  document.querySelector("#par").style.backgroundColor = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"> 
  <p id="par"></p> 
  <button id="btn" onClick="randomQuote();getRandomColor()">Next quote</button> 
</div>
```

Comment: Check the new snippet using Random colors

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
var counter = 0;
function randomQuote () {
   var array = [1,20,50,100];
   document.getElementById("par").innerHTML(array[counter++]);
}
```

Comment: none of all answers is working what i wanted. It must me because of my insufficient elaboration...i will try to be more specific

 <div id="wrapper">
   <p id="par"></p>
  <button id="btn" onClick="randomQuote();getRandomColor()">Next quote</button>
 </div>

Answer (score 0):

save the index, increment it on each click and then reset it when its undefined.

```js
var index = -1;

function randomQuote() {
  var array = [1, 20, 50, 100];
  document.getElementById('par').innerText = (array[++index] || array[index=0]);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="quotes">
    <p id="par"></p>
  </div>
  <button class="btn" onClick="randomQuote()">button</button>
</div>
```